# Changing job shortly after starting a new job - how soon is too soon?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, job-change

I have a lot of job experience but I was out of my normal profession (software development) for a number of years for family reasons. When I decided to go back to the profession, I was finding it difficult to find many jobs to apply for in my particular niche (a quirk of my local area). So 3 months ago I took a low paying position with a small local startup company to start getting industry experience under my belt again. But the salary is definitely too low for me to be able to stay long term. And I am now seeing that there is a pickup in my area for my speciality with the larger and better paying companies.

How soon is too soon for me to start applying to the higher paying jobs?

Will it be viewed negatively that I am looking to move on again so soon? How can I mitigate any such negative view in my applications and interviews?

I think my background and reasons are different than in the similar question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118/switching-jobs-how-soon-is-too-soon), so should require a different answer.

Comment: "*I think my background and reasons are different than in the similar question here, so should require a different answer.*" That's irrelevant when you're asking the general question of how employers look at short stays so your core question is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

If you can stick it out that long try and make it to the year - you won't (or shouldn't!) be labelled as a job hopper with only one short stay on you resume but given you have been out of the sector for a while it would be good to have a some demonstrable experience on your record to help bolster potential employers' confidence.

Answer (score -1):

> If your current salary is too low for you, then it's never too soon - you have to do what's right for you and your family.

By all means, apply for these roles that are coming up because if you're successful in getting the job, then a) your new employer is accepting your employment history and are confident in you/your ability and b) you get your desired salary.

With that said, if you job hop too often in the future then you will start getting asked about it. I've recently been asked about my 'job hopping' but had to clarify that 90% of my experience has been in consulting and contracting which are, naturally, shorter term.

Answer (score -1):

It’s time to leave - not too early, not too late - when you have a signed contract for another job. Don’t worry about anything else.

If an employer thinks it’s too early, they won’t give you a job, so this sorts out itself. Good idea if you look for a job where you can stay long term.